# Using LINQ expression to retrieve IEnumerable of properties from IEnumerable of POCO

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to iterate an IEnumerable of an object using LINQ, and pull out a certain property of every object into an IEnumerable of the type of that property.

I am currently doing it with the SelectMany LINQ expression, but instead of returning an `IEnumerable<string>` which I want (as the property is a string), it is returning an `IEnumerable<char>`

```
var propertyValues = objectCollection.SelectMany(o => o.Value);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is returning an `IEnumerable<char>` then that is what it is.  At a guess you want to use Select() and not SelectMany(), I would guess it is flattening a bunch of strings as an `IEnumerable<char>`.  If you can post more code that shows what is in `objectCollection` we might be able to help more.

**EDIT**

bit more code to illustrate my point

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
stringList.Add("string1");
stringList.Add("string2");
IEnumerable<char> chars = stringList.SelectMany(x => x);
```

Comment: But there are no char properties - the value property is a string, there is no mention of char anywhere!

Comment: @dormisher: Yes there is: `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Answer (score 5):

you want `Select` instead of `SelectMany`. `SelectMany` will *flatten* a sequence of sequences. You're basically projecting to a sequence of strings - and a string is a sequence of characters, so `Selectmany` is flattening the sequence of strings to a single sequence of characters.

Try:

```
var propertyValues = objectCollection.Select(o => o.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Select(o => o.Value)`. SelectMany flattens collections, so it's selecting all your string `Value` properties, then flattens each into a list of chars.